# android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: android

i m replacing my fragment through onclick button but getting this error plz help
this is my detail activity fragment

```
public class DetailActivityFragment extends Fragment{

    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView details;
    Button button;
    public DetailActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);


       Bundle getBundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();

        String name = getBundle.getString("NAME");
        textView= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bioname);
        textView.setText(name);
        imageView= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(getBundle.getInt("IMAGE"));
        Log.v("test", "images are coming");
         button= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.quickfacts);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fragment = new QuickFacts();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.quickfacts, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

this is my qucikfacts.xml  which is a part of quickfact fragment on which fragmeht is replacing on click

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/quickfacts"
    ></FrameLayout>
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />
```

this is my fragment detail in which i have that button

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bioname" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/quickfacts"

    android:text="Quick Facts"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25sp"

    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/quick_facts"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/biodetail"

    android:text="Biography"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25sp"

    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/quick_facts"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/exit"

    android:text="Exit"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25sp"

    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/quick_facts"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/quotes"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/biodetail"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/quotes"

    android:text="Quotes"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25sp"

    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/quick_facts"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/quickfacts"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp" />
```

this is the logcat

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.example.rahul.famousbiography, PID: 723
                                                                           java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.configureTransitions(BackStackRecord.java:1132)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.beginTransition(BackStackRecord.java:1039)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:658)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Your code is not related to your error. Put your all code and logcat clearly.

Comment: AppCombatButton is child of View not ViewGroup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.quickfacts, fragment);` Are you sure your fragment is inside your button ?

`button= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.quickfacts);` Or is your button `frame layout ?`

I assume your id is wrong in either one of them.

Comment: yes that button belongs to detailactivityfragment xml file and what i m doing this after onclick the fragment will replace and move to another

Comment: @rahulvyas Your button and frame layout has same id. try giving unique id for each in the xml file.

Comment: @rahulvyas no mention, i also often made such mistakes in the beginning due to copy pasting my layout ;) in future keep it as a practice to have unique id's for all ui elements. It will also help you when you need to do some search.